# PHP is Syntax wired behavior

Tags: php, execution

Today , i've seen some wiered syntax of PHP .

```
$x="{${phpinfo()}}";
```

Try to execute the above code and Bammm you will see the phpinfo() is getting executed , My eye brows got raised. however i've declared `$x` variable as string.

Look this vulnerability PHP code found in the Ebay. I am wondering how this got executed.

http://www.secalert.net/2013/12/13/ebay-remote-code-execution/

Comment: What part of this do you find weird?

Comment: Why? Why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: You will get Notice: Undefined variable, because phpinfo() does not return anything.

Comment: check out the , I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

It's not weird. It's how that's intended to be. [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) will output data in any case. If you want to capture it's output, then use [`ob_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) (output buffering) functions:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//var_dump($data);
```

Your problem isn't related to syntax.

Comment: You're right , this isn't wired. But have a look at this vulnerability. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

PHPinfo is a function that returns information in HTML form about the PHP environment on your server (see https://www.php.net/phpinfo for more information). To run PHPinfo, you must save the following code in a file on your computer using the text editor:

phpinfo ();